# Need code to let user make repeated attempts

Tags: python

I am new to coding so I am trying to create a Rock Paper Scissors Game. I have almost completed the game, but when the user and computer input the same number, I want the program to repeat until either one of the player wins. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

```
game = input("Want to play Rock Paper Scissors? (Y/N) ")
if game == "Y":
  print("1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors")
  print('')
  user = int(input("You have one chance of beating me. Input a number. "))
  print('')

  import random

  computer = random.randint(1,3)

  if user == 1 and computer == 1:
    print("Must play again! We both played Rock!")
  elif user == 1 and computer == 2:
    print("You lose! You played Rock and I played Paper!")
  elif user == 1 and computer == 3:
    print("You win! You played Rock and I played Scissors!")
  elif user == 2 and computer == 1:
    print("You win! You played Paper and I played Rock!")
  elif user == 2 and computer == 2:
    print("Must play again! We both played Paper!")
  elif user == 2 and computer == 3:
    print("You lose! You played Paper and I played Scissors!")
  elif user == 3 and computer == 1:
    print("You lose! You played Scissors and I played Rock!")
  elif user == 3 and computer == 2:
    print("You win! You played Scissors and I played Paper!")
  elif user == 3 and computer == 3:
    print("Must play again! We both played Scissors!")
  else:
    print("Not a number.")  
else:
  print("Fine. Bye.")
```

Comment: Put this code into `while True`

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: [Infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop).

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole if-elif-block in a while-loop that will repeat until you have a winner. In order to determine if there is a winner, use a boolean variable.

```
winner = False
while not winner:
    if ...... ## Your if-elif-block

    elif user == 1 and computer == 2:
        print("You lose! You played Rock and I played Paper!")
        winner = True

    ## Your remaining if-elif-block
```

You only put the command `winner=True` in the command blocks of the conditions that have a winner. So, the loop will continue until you hit one of these conditions.

You could also choose to use a more advanced winner variable (0 for draw, 1 for player, 2 for computer) to use the value in a goodbye-message.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a while loop, breaking when a condition is satisfied.

```
while True:
    if (condition):
        print("")
        break
    ...
```

The while statement repeats the loop until one of the conditions is satisfied. The break statement causes the program to exit the loop and move on to the next executable statement.

Answer (score 0):

(to learn more google anything in quotes :)

using a "while loop" to create a "game loop". I learned this trick from making small games in python. Also, you want to learn to use "classes" as the logic and the code can be improved using "OOP concepts".T code has been tested and works.

```
import random

#Create a "function" that meets the requirements of a "game loop"
def gameloop():
    game = input("Want to play Rock Paper Scissors? (Y/N) ")

    
    if game == "Y":

         #Create a "while loop" to host the logic of the game. 
         #Each If statement will enable one "rule" of the game logic.
         #game logic could be redesigned as an "Event".
         #You can add a game "Event System" to your future project backlog

        winner = False
        while not winner:
            print("1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors")
            print('')
            user = int(
                input("You have one chance of beating me. Input a number. "))
            print('')

            computer = random.randint(1, 3)

            if user == 1 and computer == 2:
                print("You lose! You played Rock and I played Paper!")
                winner = True

            elif user == 1 and computer == 3:
                print("You win! You played Rock and I played Scissors!")
                winner = True

            elif user == 2 and computer == 1:
                print("You win! You played Paper and I played Rock!")
                winner = True

            elif user == 2 and computer == 3:
                print("You lose! You played Paper and I played Scissors!")
                winner = True

            elif user == 3 and computer == 1:
                print("You lose! You played Scissors and I played Rock!")
                winner = True

            elif user == 3 and computer == 2:
                print("You win! You played Scissors and I played Paper!")
                winner = True

            elif user == 1 and computer == 1:
                print("Must play again! We both played Rock!")

            elif user == 2 and computer == 2:
                print("Must play again! We both played Paper!")

            elif user == 3 and computer == 3:
                print("Must play again! We both played Scissors!")

            else:
                print("Not a number.")

else:
    print("game....over?")
    
gameloop()
```

I took the time to do an OOP Class example too! it could be optimized in many ways. However, I hope it shows you the next level of study! I also hope it helps you look into all the crazy design patterns and Game Programming Techniques you can apply as you learn.

```
import random

# we can create a player class to be used as an "interface" as we design the games logic
# this will let us scale the features be build in our game
# in this case i will leave it to you to add Wins to the scoreboard to help you learn

class player:
    # your games requerment wants your players to make a choice from 1-3
    choice = 0
    # your games may requerment a player to be defined as the winner
    win = 0
    # your games may requerment a player to be defined as the losser
    loss = 0


class game:
    # by using classes and OOP we can scale the data and logic of your game
    # here we create instances of the class player and define new objects based on your "requerments"
    # your "requerments" where to have one Computer as a player, and one user as a player
    computer = player()
    user = player()

    # this "function" will create a Scoreboard feature that can be called in the 'game loop' or in a future "event" of the game.
    # Like a "Game Stats stage" at the end of the game
    def Scoreboard(self, computer, user):
        Computer = computer.loss
        User = user.loss
        print("+============= FINAL RESULTS: SCOREBOARD!! ======+ ")
        print(" ")
        print("Computer losses: ", Computer)
        print("Player losses: ", User)
        print(" ")

    # Create a "function" that meets the requirements of a "game loop"
    def main_loop(self, computer, user):
        gameinput = input("Want to play Rock Paper Scissors? (Y/N) ")

        if gameinput == "Y":

           # Create a "while loop" to host the logic of the game.
           # Each If statement will enable one "rule" of the game logic.
           # game logic could be redesigned as an "Event".
           # You can add a game "Event System" to your future project backlog

            winner = False
            while not winner:
                print("1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors")
                print('')

                # we create 'Player1' as the user
                Player1 = user
                
                # we change the 'Player1' 'choice' to the user input
                Player1.choice = int(
                    input("You have one chance of beating me. Input a number. "))

                print('')
                
                # we pull in to the game the computer player and call them 'Player1'
                Player2 = computer
                
                # we change the 'Player2' 'choice' to a random number
                Player2.choice = random.randint(1, 3)
            

                if user.choice == 1 and computer.choice == 2:
                    print("You lose! You played Rock and I played Paper!")
                    winner = True
                    user.loss += 1
                elif user.choice == 1 and computer.choice == 3:
                    print("You win! You played Rock and I played Scissors!")
                    winner = True
                    computer.loss += 1
                elif user.choice == 2 and computer.choice == 1:
                    print("You win! You played Paper and I played Rock!")
                    winner = True
                    computer.loss += 1
                elif user.choice == 2 and computer.choice == 3:
                    print("You lose! You played Paper and I played Scissors!")
                    winner = True
                    user.loss += 1
                elif user.choice == 3 and computer.choice == 1:
                    print("You lose! You played Scissors and I played Rock!")
                    winner = True
                    user.loss += 1
                elif user.choice == 3 and computer.choice == 2:
                    print("You win! You played Scissors and I played Paper!")
                    winner = True
                    computer.loss += 1
                elif user.choice == 1 and computer.choice == 1:
                    print("Must play again! We both played Rock!")
                elif user.choice == 2 and computer.choice == 2:
                    print("Must play again! We both played Paper!")
                elif user.choice == 3 and computer.choice == 3:
                    print("Must play again! We both played Scissors!")
                else:
                    print("Not a number.")
            # by returning "self" you call the same 'instances' of game that you will define below
            return self.Scoreboard(user, computer)
        else:
            print("game....over?")


# define Instance of game as "test_game"
test_game = game()

# run game loop

test_game.main_loop()
```